# finding the length of a portion of a csv file in python

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to get the average of part of a column in a csv file but I haven't been able to find the length.  I noticed that when I run len it's counting the amount of characters and not the length from 2021-2003 (len should be 18).

*Note: This is for a class and will not be using pandas

```
import csv

with open('C:/Users/lblortz/Desktop/LakeMead.csv', newline='') as csv_file:
    list_name = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')

  index=0
    total=0.0
    count=0.0

    for YEAR, AVGELEVATION, AVGCONTENT, AVGINFLOW, AVGOUTFLOW, AVGHIGHTEMP, AVGLOWTEMP, AVGWATERTEMP in list_name:

        if index != 0:
            if int(YEAR)>=2003:
                print(len(list_name))
                total= float(AVGELEVATION) + total     
        index+=1
        
    count=total/len(list_name)
    print("average is",count)
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. [Please do not post pictures of your code.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: paste your code as text not screenshots , edit your question

Comment: the same with your sample data

Comment: You can use pandas for the operations to be done on csv. It's the best way to play with tables

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.  Your code is pretty good as is.

For finding the average of total over a number of years, yeah, you've got an issue in that here:

```py
count=total/len(YEAR)
```

it looks like you are equating `len(YEAR)` with "all the cells (rows) in the YEAR column", but you've found out that it really means "the length of characters in the value stored in the variable `YEAR`", and you set that value in your loop—so it's the length of characters of the *last year* your loop counted.

The quick fix for this is to keep track of how many years have been counted:

```py
index=0
total=0.0
count=0.0
years=[]  # create an empty list and add years to it as they are counted
...

        if int(YEAR) >= 2003:
            years.append(YEAR)
            ...

count=total/len(years)
```

For dealing with the CSV in general, I also recommend this small change...

**your index counter**

It looks like `index` only exists to say whether you've iterated past the header.  You can manually read the first row (the header) and do nothing with it (discard it) like this:

```py
list_name=csv.reader(csv_file)
next(list_name)
...
```

`next()` is the Python way of manually iterating an *iterable*, which is what `csv.reader()` makes.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!  Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Since this seems to help, please accept by clicking the check-mark under/next to the score for this answer.